# linphone-desktop on Windows 10 compile error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, cmake, linphone

I'm trying to build linphone-desktop on Windows 10

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop

But when I build the project using Visual Studio 2015, I get this error on building EP_vpx:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 258.
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? I couldn't find anything helpful in issues and stackoverflow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the problem by:

Using QT 5.9.8 exactly.

Defining these in the System Environment Variables:

```
Qt5_DIR="C:\Qt\Qt5.9.8\5.9.8\msvc2015\lib\cmake"

PATH:"C:\Qt\Qt5.9.8\5.9.8\msvc2015\bin"

PATH:"C:\Qt\Qt5.9.8\5.9.8\mingw53_32\bin"

PATH:"C:\Qt\Qt5.9.8\Tools\mingw530_32\bin"
```

Passing the DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION in the python command:

```
python prepare.py -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DENABLE_DOC=OFF -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1
```

For those who don't know, You should have installed Windows 8.1 SDK on your Windows, too.